# Kibana - Only visualize messages under some condition

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I need to visualize only messages that has some field (named `Status`). That field doesn't appear in all docs.

I've tried to add a sub-bucket and wrote `Status` as filter.. but I didn't get any results.

Current messages split (Currently only by process name.. as mentioned, I need only those that has `Status` field in docs):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search docs that has status field by searching as `_exists_:Status` in the search box.

Check that: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_field_names

Comment: Can I embed it in my visualization without writing it in the search box each time ?

Comment: You can save visualization with that search and use that visualization in dashboards. If you mean that.

Comment: But how ? when I'm trying to save visualization with that search, after I reopen I see again "*" instead "_exists_:Status"

Comment: Did you saved the visualization?

Comment: I did save.. still goes back to "*"

Comment: What is your version?

Answer (score 1):

You should use filter. Please try to change it as given in below image:

[image]

Comment: Can I add filter to my visualize WITHOUT using a sub bucket ? (I mean as part of the first split).

Comment: Yes, you can do it