# How to visualize message from Kafka in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I am gathering data with **Packetbeat**, **Metricbeat**, and **Filebeat** and send them to **Logstash** through **Kafka** and then **Elasticsearch**, finally to **Kibana**.

When I didn't use Kafka and Logstash. I could easily visualize in Kibana through default dashboard setup and many available fields. I can create dashboards showing CPU, RAM, disk space metric data.

However, when I use Kafka and Logstash, all the data is stored in **`message`** field. I don't have many fields which I can use to visualize it in dashboards. I think Kafka puts everything in the message. I want to visualize all the system metrics data and others.

[image]

[image]

> How can I utilize data in the **`message`** field to visualize it?

The following link appears as a similar question, but my situation is a little bit different, and it does not solve my case. 
[SO similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37130730/10504469)

---

My **Logstash** configuration :

```
input {
    kafka {
            bootstrap_servers => "localhost:9092"
            topics => ["testkafka"]
            codec => json    <=  Val's answer right here.
    }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => ["testkafka"]
    codec => json
```

Comment: So the beats send to Kafka, and Logstash consumes the topics and sends to ES? Can you share your Logstash configuration? It's where the magic should happen

Comment: @Val yup right away Sir~ I'll update it!

Comment: you could, f.e, apply the key-value filter for logstash, in order to elastic to be able to store the metrics individually

Comment: @aran thanks for tips. I think that's what Val is trying to show me.

Comment: Ok, you can start by simply adding `codec => 'json'` in your kafka input and that should get you a bit further

Comment: @Val Okay I'll do that.  apostrophe is mandatory?

Comment: no, you can go without

Comment: @Val  message seems to look different now in Kibana after adding codec =>'json'

Comment: Yes, it should be parsed as JSON and your documents should now have all the fields

Comment: @Val they look a bit different, but everythin is in the message still :(  I'll post a pic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to make sure that Logstash parses the messages it gets from Kafka with the JSON codec

```
kafka {
        bootstrap_servers => "localhost:9092"
        topics => ["testkafka"]
        codec => json                              <-- add this line
}
```

Comment: I tried without apostrophe, and it worked!  thank you!